# Searching WordPress user_meta values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I developed a matrimonial website. And what I did is to use `user ID` and store all values into wordpress user meta table.

Like

```
umeta_id    user_id       meta_key      meta_value
1              5         full_name     Gautam Menariya
2              5            DOB          1/1/1985
3              5         occupation        Job
4              5         education     Engineering
5              5        education_in   Information Technology
6              5           gender        male
```

Everything is fine until I start developing search part.

I want to search all persons who are male, education is engineering, education_in information Technology and has occupation is job.

I tried, but when I have approximately 500 records, the speed of searching is very slow. Can anyone provide best and fast searching method or should I use saperat table for all attributes for the users.

Comment: Show the method you're using.

Comment: I tried, what i did is first filter all values using education, then remaining values by occupation and so on....   I tried to write best query but i don't understand how to  do this

Comment: can you show us the specific code you wrote?

Comment: I used something like this  `$query = "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE (meta_value LIKE '$occupation') 
    AND (meta_key = 'occupation') 
    AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value LIKE '$education') AND (meta_key = 'education'))";

$rows = $wpdb->get_results($query)`

Comment: @GautamMenariya May i know, which theme did you use to build a matrimonial site - i have a similar requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to run directly a query to the database, use $wpdb
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: can you please write query because i tried and dont find a way to do this in a single query